# Calculation Year of Age in a .CSV file by Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, calculation

I have a `Customer_Profile.csv` file that contains a column `Birthday` and values are like `19460620` (YearMonthDay) format.

I want to calculate only the year of age from the present / now day. In addition, after calculating the age, I also want to categorize / group the age in a new column named `Age_Group`.

For example, the age group should be as follows:

Age between 10 to 20 is group 1
Age between 21 to 30 is group 2
Age between 31 to 40 is group 3

and so on. Any idea to write python script for the above tasks.

Comment: Look at your question, format and content, and ask yourself if or why would anyone would want to spend time on it... [ask]

Comment: Yea I started to answer this, I know how to. I'm just not about to even try to decipher this word salad though

Answer (score 0):

you can easily parse the birth date using `datetime.datetime.strptime` like this:

```
birth_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("19460620", "%Y,%m%d")
```

and the current time:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

then you can get the age using the following:

```
birthday_passed = (now.month > birth_date.month) or 
                  (now.month == birth_date.month and now.day == birth_date.day)
age = now.year - birth_date.year
if birthday_passed:
    age -= 1
```

to group your ages you can use integer division:

```
group = (age - 1) // 10
```

The csv reading and writing is easy enough to do using pandas. just look up `pandas.read_csv` and `pandas.to_csv`